# Using GroupBy with DateTime in Pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data that looks like this that I get from an API (of course in JSON form):

```
0,1500843600,8872
1,1500807600,18890
2,1500811200,2902
.
.
.
```

where the second column is the date/time in ticks, and the third column is some value. I basically have the data for every hour of the day, for every day for a couple of months. Now, what I want to achieve is that I want to get the minimum value for the third column for every week. I have the code segment below, which correctly returns the minimum value for me, but apart from returning the minimum value, I also want to return the specific `Timestamp` as which date/time the lowest that week occurred. How can I modify my code below, so I can get also the `Timestamp` along with the minimum value.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['Timestamp', 'Value'])

# dic holds the data that I get from my API.
for i in range(len(dic)):
    df.loc[i] = [dic[i][1], dic[i][2]]

df['Timestamp'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], unit='s')
df.sort_values(by=['Timestamp'])
df.set_index(df['Timestamp'], inplace=True)

df.groupby([pandas.Grouper(key='Timestamp', freq='W-MON')])['Value'].min()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) for index of `min` value of column `Timestamp` and then select by `loc`:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], unit='s')

df = df.loc[df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Timestamp', freq='W-MON')])['Value'].idxmin()]
print (df)
            Timestamp  Value
2 2017-07-23 12:00:00   2902
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Timestamp', freq='W-MON')])['Value'].idxmin())
Timestamp
2017-07-24    2
Freq: W-MON, Name: Value, dtype: int64
```